# ActionbarSerlock sample project not generating R file

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I've been trying to learn how to use the [ActionbarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) to customize my application and add an actionbar and use fragments.

I downloaded the zip file from their website and added the `library` folder as a new android project.

then, I made sure that it's has the `isLibrary` checked to true.

after that, I created a new android project from existing and added the `JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-88fc341/samples/fragments` but suddenly I saw all these error appear.

I made sure that it imported the `actionbarSherlock` project, and after that I deleted the `Gen` library both manually (delete) and via the `project>clean>clean all` option, but nothing generated the R file.

the only thing being generated is a `BuildConfig` file but I can't force the R file generation.

any thoughts?

***BuildConfig.Java:***

```
package com.actionbarsherlock.sample.fragments;

public final class BuildConfig {
    public final static boolean DEBUG = true;
}
```

Comment: @JakeWharton, as I wrote. the errors come from not having an R file. it doesn't recognize the xml for this project because the R file wasn't generated

Comment: Are you compiling with Android 4.0+? Uses JDK 1.6 compliance in your project java settings? Referencing the library from the sample?

Comment: the library is referenced, the target SDK is 15 the minSdk is 7, the JDK version is: `java version "1.6.0_29"`

Comment: What version of Android are you compiling with? JDK compliance can be found under "Java Compiler" in the project properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.

So, after talking to Jake Wharton on the [IRC channel](http://webchat.freenode.net/) (#android-dev), he posted the comment here, and I checked to see if the build target was correct. unfortunately since the `minSdk` was 7, the build target was not 15 is specified in the manifest but 2.1 :S

anyway, the solution was to change the target build to the correct one (15 for actionbarSherlock) and clean and build again...

thanks a bunch Jake.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. The sherlock version that i use defined an API level in the manifest which was not installed on my system before. After installing the API, in my case lvl 16, everything worked fine again.